# What does Lev 18:18 "Rival Wife" Mean?

Tags: old-testament, marriage, leviticus, family, polygamy

Leviticus 18:18:

> Do not take your wife’s sister as a rival wife and have sexual relations with her while your wife is living.

I always wondered why it says it like this. Instead of, "do not marry your wife's sister while she is alive," it says not to take her as a "rival wife" specifically.

What does that mean?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this would be better asked on [Biblical Hermeneutics](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @LeeWoofenden: Rather than closing it, can't it be moved instead?

Comment: @Wtrmute Mods can move questions to other sites.